# Facebook Account Kit Deprecated

Tags: account-kit

I [just saw](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2019/09/09/account-kit-services-no-longer-available-starting-march) that [facebook account](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/accountkit/) kit is being **deprecated**. There isn't much information about what's the reason behind its depreciation or what could be the next steps/alternatives.

- Does anyone know why they deprecated it? Any technical insights/learnings?
- What are the alternatives now? or are they planing any successor of it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, As per official statement : from September 9, 2019: Account Kit will stop integrating with new apps. Existing integrations will continue to function normally.

Source [1](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2019/09/09/account-kit-services-no-longer-available-starting-march),[2](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/accountkit/)

> Does anyone know why they deprecated it? Any technical
>   insights/learnings?

"The product has yielded high maintenance costs, but relatively low adoption". Read full details [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/accountkit/faq).

> What are the alternatives now? or are they planing any successor of
>   it?

They not announce any successor for it as far as i know, but there are many other alternatives available as open source which obviously have certain limitations. What I am using currently will mention here.

- [True Caller](https://truecaller4developers.gitbook.io/truecallersdk/android/implementing-user-flow-for-your-app) SDK :   It require true caller app to be installed in user device.
- [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/phone-auth) Phone Authentication
- Third Party SMS API : Obviously, it would be a paid api, Many service providers are available in market. I am not promoting any one here but one is suggested by google itself [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/sms-retriever/verify) called twilio. Just a extra point : In this 3rd case, for understanding the flow ["SMS Retriever API"](https://developers.google.com/identity/sms-retriever/user-consent/overview) may worth reading for some one.