# Use Firebase to login? Accountkit alternative

Tags: ios, firebase-authentication, parse-server, account-kit

Facebook recently very unfortunately deprecated AccountKit.
One alternative could be Firebase Phone Auth as described here:

[Facebook Account Kit Deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57868800/facebook-account-kit-deprecated)

I already use Firebase in combination with Parse-server. Is there a way to authenticate
using Firebase in iOS, and then transfer/use that login to generate a user in Parse-Server?

Comment: It is possible but you'd need to create a custom Auth Adapter. You can see the current ones [here](https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server/tree/master/src/Adapters/Auth) and use them as template for creating the new one. You can either submit a PR to incorporate it to Parse Server or you can install locally only for your app.

Comment: Thank you. It seems though that the auth flow is not your typical oauth2 for a phone number. You only get the end result (userId) directly from firebase, there is no server side secret token verification that I could trigger as far as I could find out. I might be totally off though. Did you try something similar with firebase before?

Comment: I'd try to use the Firebase SDK to do the phone authentication then send the returned credentials to Parse Server. Then your adapter could validate it in Firebase.

Comment: Thanks, this works! Can you please post this as an official answer so I can mark it as solved (and give you the points)?

Comment: No problem. I am glad you figured it out :)